# Query to find users who share same account number

Tags: mysql

I am currently learning mysql. I was able to create a table named `user` (referenced below). Each user has a unique id. Some users share the same account number. I am having no luck in writing a query that will show results of  users who share the same account number. How would I go about that?

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `role` enum('default','admin','owner') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id, a.account from users u,
(select account from users
group by account
having count(*)>1) a
where u.account=a.account
order by u.account
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 SELECT * FROM `user`
 WHERE account IN (SELECT account FROM user GROUP BY account HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id, b.id 
from users as a, users as b
where a.account=b.account and a.id < b.id;
```

This finds pairs of users who share an account.

This has some drawbacks:

1. There are M*(M-1)/2 such pairs whenever M people share an account.
2. It does a table self join, so time ~ O(N^2)